# Cannot find symbol in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building a simple Android application from scratch where I'm trying to show a grid view on my landing page. For that I imported a package in my `MainActivity.java` file as shown below:

```
import android.widget;
```

When I perform `Build -> Make project` action I get  following error:

> Error:(15, 15) error: cannot find symbol class widget

Not sure why compiler is treating `android.widget` as a class name when it is effectively a namespace/package. I'm from a C# background completely new to java and android. I searched a bit and I get that I should be adding a reference to a jar file which is equivalent to adding a reference to a .Net assembly in C#. I'm not sure about which jar file I'm missing and how to add its reference in Android Studio. Kindly help.

Comment: because you write it like that. shouldn't there be a class name at the end or at least `import android.widget.*;`?

Comment: As you said c# , are you trying Xamarin or Android Studio?

Comment: I'm using android studio.

Comment: what do you expect `import android.widget;` to do?

Comment: @njzk2 I expect that `import android.widget;` statement should import all the classes present inside `import android.widget` package. I wanted to use `GridView` class (which is found inside `android.widget` package) in my `MainActivity.java` file. If I don't use the import statement then possibly I'll have to use fully qualified type names which will look verbose.

Comment: @Baby I'm sorry about that. I didn't know that namespace import statement work that way in Java. I'm from C# background so just tried the way it works in C#.

Comment: @RBT ok. I don't know where you read that this should behave that way, but you should ditch that source of information, as it is not reliable. (Also, android studio does the right imports for you when you autocomplete the class names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Java !! I am actually going now the other way.

Anyways, importing packages in Java (or namespaces in c#) works more or less the same way. The way you imported the package , makes Java think that there is a class (Type) at the end.

So, if you want to import the whole widget package, just change it to

```
import android.widget.*;
```

Or if you interested to import a more specific Class (which is mostly the case), then import some class like this -

```
import android.widget.AbsListView;
```

Please go through - [Java Type import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Android, RBT.
I think you should change that import to

`import android.widget.*;`

Or you can import it later when you use it.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you for your support brother. your answer was equally correct. It is just that Dbzmania had answered the question 6 minutes ahead of you so I accepted his. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: ohh my bad. `answered x minutes ago` essentially means - higher the number x means more older the answer is. I misinterpreted it otherwise in a rush :P. Still I upvoted your post as a courtesy. The accepted answer is more descriptive. Thanks again.

Comment: @RBT you was wrong man. Dbzmania 14mins ago while me 20mins ago. LOL

Comment: That's what I said - `I misinterpreted it in a rush`.